# Percent Down / Up curve

Tags: functions, recreational-mathematics, percentages

If I create a curve where, starting from a given $Y_{0}$, each new $y$ is down of $p$% and then up of $p$% (that is, the same percentage), is it known by some name?

What could be suitable equations to represent (draw) it ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reducing value $v$ by $p \%$ gives $(1-\frac p {100})v$. Increasing value $v$ by $p\%$ gives $(1 + \frac p {100})v$.

Putting those together, we find $$Y_{n+1} = \left( \frac{100-p}{100} \right) \left( \frac{100+p}{100}\right) Y_n = \frac{10000-p^2}{10000} Y_n.$$

We can apply that formula repeatedly to find:
$$\begin{align}
Y_{n} &= \frac{10000-p^2}{10000} Y_{n-1} \\
&= \left(\frac{10000-p^2}{10000}\right) \left( \frac{10000-p^2}{10000} \right) Y_{n-2} \\
&= \cdots \\
&= \left(\frac{10000-p^2}{10000}\right)^n Y_0.
\end{align}$$

Now that we've found a formula, we find that your sequence is a [geometric progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression) with ratio $\frac{10000-p^2}{10000}$. If you really want to see a picture, you could use WolframAlpha. For example, here's a [sample link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=ListPlot%5BTable%5B%7Bn%2C%20%28%28100-10%29%2F100%29%5ECeiling%5Bn%2F2%5D%20*%20%28%28100%2B10%29%2F100%29%5EFloor%5Bn%2F2%5D%7D%2C%20%7Bn%2C%200%2C%20200%7D%5D%5D) where I used command `ListPlot[Table[{n, ((100-10)/100)^Ceiling[n/2] * ((100+10)/100)^Floor[n/2]}, {n, 0, 200}]]` to get this picture (with $p=10, Y_0=1$)

[image]

Comment: Thank you David, that is very interesting, and provides the value after n steps. Is there any way to find the equation of an actual curve representing this? That is for instance something I can plug in a function calculator and draw a function similar to that in the picture (either differentiable or not) ?

Comment: @Jada I've edited my post to add a graph + link showing how to make more graphs like this in WolframAlpha.

Comment: Ah ok, I see thank you! I was thinking about some kind of "equation" (just like those one can type into Desmos or similar visualizers), but probably is not doable or complicated :-)